# Ubuntu 16.04 with LAMP - MySQL 5.7 show_compatibility_56

Tags: 16.04, server, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

Recently, I decided to get a VPS server and host my own forums as we grew to big for your average shared hosting platform. I thought it would be easy to setup and get going, and it has been for the most part, but I have hit a brick wall with a hellish MySQL error.

Basically, I am trying to upload my old database inside PHPMYADMIN, but I keep getting the same error bounce back. I have followed some excellent guides, such as those from Digital Ocean, but there doesn't seem to be much on this error, and the information is out there isn't working for me.

Here is the error: Error SQL query: Documentation

/!50112 SELECT COUNT() INTO @is_rocksdb_supported FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSION_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME='rocksdb_bulk_load' */ MySQL said: Documentation

3167 - The 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SESSION_VARIABLES' feature is disabled; see the documentation for 'show_compatibility_56'

I have tried adding "show_compatibility_56 = ON" inside my config file which is /etc/mysql/my.cnf, I get the following error:

"Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code." add when I go to PHPMYADMIN it says "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed." and " #2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)."

I can tell you show_compatibility_56 is turned off as it shows it is turned off inside PHPMYADMIN.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue? I have been trying to fix it for nearly a week now, and I just can't find a fix for it.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with LAMP

I appreciate any help anyone can offer me.

Regards, Carl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**

This is the information I found:
1. Problem description:

When performing a MySQL database backup, the following error message is received in the backup report:

mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */* FROM `GLOBAL_STATUS`': The 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_STATUS' feature is disabled: see the documentation for 'show_compatibility_56' (3167)

2. Cause:

show_compatibility_56 is deprecated

3. Resolution:

Run the following query in your MySQL database:

```
set @@global.show_compatibility_56=ON;
```

So it looks like it was a very simple fix after all. I ran the code in the MYSQL console inside PHPMYADMIN.

Credit for the fix goes to this page: https://support.servosity.com/hc/en-us/articles/221071687-ISSUE-The-INFORMATION-SCHEMA-GLOBAL-STATUS-feature-is-disabled-see-the-documentation-for-show-compatibility-56-